# Something happen with revealViewController() in IOS

Tags: ios, swift, swift2

I have two page, and I want to back and forth between 2 page

Case 1 :

```
- page 1 : I use self.revealViewController().pushFrontViewController(viewLogin, animated: true)
```

However in page 2 : I can't go back page 1

Case 2 :

```
- page 1 : I use self.presentViewController(viewLogin, animated: true, completion: nil)
- page 2 : I use self.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)
```

It can go previous page, but I can't use **revealViewController()** for menu.

I am tied for problem.
I need help.Someone can help me.
Thank you so much for reading.

Comment: `self.dismissViewControllerAnimated` must be called on the view controller that presented the current view controller. In most case, you will have to call `self.presentingViewController.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)`.

Comment: why don't you just use the standard navigation controllers of the SDK, which presented by Apple as default?

Comment: Raphael
thanks for your answer but if 
page 1:  page 1 : I use self.revealViewController().pushFrontViewController(viewLogin, animated: true)
page 2 : self.presentingViewController.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)
page 2 not go back page 1?

Comment: You can help me solve this problem??

Comment: i use library : SWRevealViewController.